# Synapse Analytics sql on-demand sync with spark pool is very slow to query

Tags: apache-spark, azure-synapse, external-tables

I have files loaded into an azure storage account gen2, and am using Azure Synapse Analytics to query them. Following the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-spark-tables, I should be able to create a spark sql table to query the partitioned data, and thus subsequently use the metadata from spark sql in my sql on demand query to given the line in the doc: `When a table is partitioned in Spark, files in storage are organized by folders. Serverless SQL pool will use partition metadata and only target relevant folders and files for your query`

My data is partitioned in ADLS gen2 as:

[image]

Running the query in a spark notebook in Synapse Analytics returns in just over 4 seconds, as it should given the partitioning:
[image]

However, now running the same query in the sql on demand sql side script never completes:
[image]

This result and extreme reduction in performance compared to spark pool is completely counter to what the documentation notes. Is there something I am missing in the query to make sql-on demand use the partitions?

Comment: Did you try using the filename/filepath property in your where clause already? 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-specific-files#filename

Comment: I am using the syncing feature synapse analytics, so that should not be necessary, correct?

Comment: dude, that's the ticket, pretty slick!! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Filepath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-specific-files#filepath) and [filename()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-specific-files#filename) functions can be used in the WHERE clause to filter the files to be read. Which that you can achieve the prunning you have been looking for.